# An anime where a male character brings back some seeds and implants it on the wrist of his daughter

Tags: darker-than-black

I have watched an anime recently, but I have forgotten its title.

It is a sci-fi anime that resembles *Black Bullet* and *Attack on Titan*, in the sense that humankind is confined within some boundary due to threats outside that boundary.

A part of the story I remember is about this male character bringing back some seeds from outside the boundary. He would water one of the seeds daily in a pot he kept in his office (if I recall correctly), while the other seed was implanted into the wrist of a female character (his daughter, if I am not wrong).

Does anyone have any idea which anime this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be [**Darker Than Black**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2025/Darker_than_Black:_Kuro_no_Keiyakusha)?

[image: Dude on the left is the protagonist]

> In Tokyo, an impenetrable field known as "Hell's Gate" appeared ten years ago. At the same time, psychics who wield paranormal powers at the cost of their conscience also emerged. Hei is one of the most powerful of these psychic agents, and along with his blind associate, Yin, works for one of the many rival agencies vying to unlock the mysteries of Hell's Gate.

A man takes a seed from Hells Gate and plants it in his daughters wrist as well as a pot in his office. This is in episode three.

[image]